# How does a Consumer thread return results back to the correct Producer thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have multiple producer threads enqueue-ing data to a threadsafe "command priority queue".

And a "command reader" consumer thread which will constantly check this "command priority queue" for data, dequeue it, and do its necessary processing. Eventually after each processing, the results needs to be returned to the correct producer thread that issued the command.

I had thought of having another threadsafe "result queue" to enqueue the results, but the problem is how could I push the data to the relevant producer thread?

Or is there any other elegant solutions/mechanisms or architectures out there I could try?

Thank you. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to model this as a producer-consumer pattern in the first place?  It sounds more like a client-server pattern. Regardless though, this question is very vague and not a very good fit for StackOverflow.  This site is better for *specifc questions* about *actual code*.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is to add an 'OnCompletion' event, (or a Task class OnCompletion function override), to the data object that is queued to the thread/s.  When whatever thread ends up doing the work on the data has finsished, it calls 'OnComplete' with the data object as a parameter.  The originating producer thread can set the OnComplete' event, (or override method), to whatever function is wants to before queueing off the data object.

The 'OnCompletion' thing could signal an event that the producer thread waits on after queueing up the task, (synchronous), or it could queue up the task object to a private 'returnedData' blocking queue of the producer thread, so that it can be dequeued and handled whenever the producer gets around to it, (async).

Edit: The data/task object should contain an exception and/or errorMessage member so that, if the thread encounters a problem with the data, it can set it appropriately before calling 'OnCompletion'.  This allows the producer thread to see if anything screwed up.